# Why does "except" work in filtering out IDs/rows, but "not in" doesn't work?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Why does "except" work in filtering out IDs/rows, but "not in" doesn't work? When I run this code, the patient_id I want filtered out are still in the results.

```
Select pm.patient_id
from PatientMedication pm
Where (pm.medicine_id = 11 or pm.medicine_id = 29)
and pm.patient_id not in 
    Select distinct patient_id from PatientMedication pm
    Where (pm.medicine_id = 11 or pm.medicine_id = 29)
    and pm.start_date < '2009-03-17'
```

But when I run this, the expected persons are "filtered" out as I desire.

```
Select pm.patient_id
   from PatientMedication pm
Where pm.medicine_id = 11 or pm.medicine_id = 29
except
    Select distinct patient_id from PatientMedication pm
    Where (pm.medicine_id = 11 or pm.medicine_id = 29)
    and pm.start_date < '2009-03-17'
```

Thanks.

Comment: What happens if you enclose with brackets the subquery? Something like `... and pm.patient_id not in (select distinct ...)`

Comment: Using the same alias name twice is just bad practice.  Even with proper ().

Comment: @Racso, your suggestion of brackets gave the same answer as using the except option.

Comment: In fact not having the () causes an error. Oops on my part. Bad code.

Answer (score 0):

Would this be what you are trying to accomplish

```
Select pm.patient_id 
from PatientMedication pm 
Where (pm.medicine_id = 11 or pm.medicine_id = 29) 
AND pm.start_date >= '2009-03-17'
```

Comment: I think so, but I also think that the question focuses on the apparently weird behavior of `not in`.